# Odoo installation Magento Connector

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, odoo-8

I am new to Odoo/OpenERP. I am trying to install odoo and odoo-magento-connector in ubuntu 14.04 using this tutorial http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2014/09/how-to-install-openerp-odoo-8-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts/ I am getting stuck in Step 6, /opt/odoo/openerp-server after typing this command i get error shown in the below

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/opt/odoo/openerp-server", line 2, in 
>       import openerp
>       File "/opt/odoo/openerp/**init**.py", line 76, in 
>       import modules
>       File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/**init**.py", line 27, in 
>       from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
>       File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 44, in 
>       from openerp.modules.module import initialize_sys_path, \
>       File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/module.py", line 37, in 
>       import unittest2
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/unittest2-1.1.0-py2.7.egg
>       /unittest2/**init**.py", line 40, in 
>       from unittest2.collector import collector
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/unittest2-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/
>       unittest2/collector.py", line 3, in 
>       from unittest2.loader import defaultTestLoader
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/unittest2-1.1.0-py2.7.egg/ 
>       unittest2/loader.py", line 13, in 
>       from unittest2 import case, suite, util
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/unittest2-1.1.0-py2.7.egg 
>       /unittest2/case.py", line 10, in 
>       import traceback2 as traceback
>       ImportError: No module named traceback2`

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this old when i had the same issue

It is a python module

```
    pip search traceback2
```

You can install like this (use sudo)

```
    pip install traceback2
```

[image]